# Java 8 way to work with an enum

Tags: java, enums, java-8

I'm wondering what the best way is in Java 8 to work with all the values of an enum. Specifically when you need to get all the values and add it to somewhere, for example, supposing that we have the following enum:

```
public enum Letter {
 A, B, C, D;
}
```

I could of course do the following:

```
for (Letter l : Letter.values()) {
    foo(l);
}
```

But, I could also add the following method to the enum definition:

```
public static Stream<Letter> stream() {
    return Arrays.stream(Letter.values());
}
```

And then replace the for from above with:

```
Letter.stream().forEach(l -> foo(l));
```

Is this approach OK or does it have some fault in design or performance? Moreover, why don't enums have a stream() method?

Comment: Why not add a method `static void forEach(Consumer<Letter> action)` to your enum? Then you can simply call it with `Letter.forEach(l -> foo(l))`.

Comment: This seems like overkill to me. Since arrays don't support the stream API I would just use a for loop and be done. It seems like you are adding complexity just to be new and shiny but it isn't gaining you anything here.

Comment: This looks like premature optimization. I would recommend doing a benchmark for your specific scenario and technology stack by using JMH or Caliper and use the *best* approach.

Comment: First get it working, then go for the performance optimizations, not the other way around.

Comment: @bhspencer that's one of the things that I was thinking, if in an effort to make the code the more java8 way I wasn't "killing a fly with a bazooka". But in other hand, the code with the stream method looks better ;)

Comment: As an aside, `forEach(l -> foo(l))`  might be better written as `forEach(foo)`.

Comment: C# people are moving uneasily when you do this - [here's why](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Comment: Note that calling `Enum.values` returns an `Enum[]`. As an array is _mutable_ the `enum` **must** return a different copy of the array each time (just in case someone mutated it); this means that any call to `Enum.values` **must** be `O(n)`. This is a flaw in the design of `enum` - an immutable `Set` would have been a much better choice - but it means that if performance is paramount then you should cache `Enum.value` in an immutable `Set` and that would already offer a `stream()` method...

Comment: @Boris the Spider: or simply use `EnumSet.allOf(Letter.class).stream()` which will use a *shared array* under the hood. Or as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29926133/2711488) points out, even doesn’t need a `Stream` when all the OP wants is `forEach(…)`.

Comment: @Holger is that correct? Looking at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/EnumSet.java?av=f) the `EnumSet` calls an `abstract addAll` method - given that `EnumSet` is also mutable - wouldn't that also have to be `O(n)`?

Comment: @Boris the Spider: No, that’s not the standard Collection `addAll` method, it’s a [special `enum` specific method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/RegularEnumSet.java#RegularEnumSet.addAll%28%29). It doesn’t even touch an array.

Comment: @Holger I wrote a quick [jmh benchmark](https://gist.github.com/bmorris591/0e0f3859cc8b7e0ab84b) to try and put some numbers to all this. Surprisingly it seems that `Enum.values()` is rather significantly faster than other approaches. Maybe I'm abusing JMH somehow...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Three questions: three-part answer:

#### Is it okay from a design point of view?

Absolutely. Nothing wrong with it. If you need to do lots of iterating over your enum, the stream API is the clean way to go and hiding the boiler plate behind a little method is fine. Although I’d consider [OldCumudgeon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/823393/oldcurmudgeon)’s [version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29922602/66686) even better.

#### Is it okay from a performance point of view?

It most likely doesn’t matter. Most of the time, enums are not that big. Therefore, whatever overhead there is for one method or the other probably doesn’t matter in 99.9% of the cases.

Of course, there are the 0.1% where it does. In that case: measure properly, with your real-world data and consumers.

If I had to bet, I’d expect the `for each` loop to be faster, since it maps more directly to the memory model, but don’t guess when talking performance, and don’t tune before there is actual need for tuning. Write your code in a way that is correct first, easy to read second and only then worry about performance of code style.

#### Why aren’t Enums properly integrated into the Stream API?

If you compare Java’s Stream API to the equivalent in many other languages, it appears seriously limited. There are various pieces that are missing (reusable Streams and Optionals as Streams, for example). On the other hand, implementing the Stream API was certainly a huge change for the API. It was postponed multiple times for a reason. So I guess Oracle wanted to limit the changes to the most important use cases. Enums aren’t used that much anyway. Sure, every project has a couple of them, but they’re nothing compared to the number of Lists and other Collections. Even when you have an Enum, in many cases you  won’t ever iterate over it. Lists and Sets, on the other hand, are probably iterated over almost every time. I assume that these were the reasons why the Enums didn’t get their own adapter to the Stream world. We’ll see whether more of this gets added in future versions. And until then you always can use `Arrays.stream`.

Comment: Regarding performance, if this is in a tight loop, then it may be worth noting that `values()` actually clones the array. So that's a good deal of allocating, `arraycopy`ing, and freeing that has to go on. Probably pretty well optimized by the JVM, but if it's possible to write `Letter[] allLetters = Letter.values()` just once and then loop over *that*, you'll get some performance gain.

Answer (score 27):

I'd go for [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html). Because `forEach()` is also defined on `Iterable`, you can avoid creating the stream altogether:

```
EnumSet.allOf(Letter.class).forEach(x -> foo(x));
```

Or with a method reference:

```
EnumSet.allOf(Letter.class).forEach(this::foo);
```

Still, the oldschool for-loop feels a bit simpler:

```
for (Letter x : Letter.values()) {
    foo(x);
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution for enums, given the use of `EnumSet`.

Comment: Even when using the stream for additional intermediate operations, e.g. `EnumSet.allOf(Letter.class) .stream().filter(…).forEach(…)`, the `EnumSet` is the preferred solution as it avoids the creation of the *temporary array* which might be more costly than the lightweight `Stream` instance (unless the JVM detects and elides the array as “defensive copy”, but even then using `EnumSet` is on par with other solutions)

Comment: Right, the trick of EnumSet is that it never allocates an enum array, but uses a bit vector instead (a single long or an array of longs depending on the count of the enum constants).

Answer (score 12):

My **guess** is that enums are limited in size (i.e the size is not limited by language but limited by usage)and thus they don't need a *native* stream api. Streams are very good when you have to manipulate transform and recollect the elements in a stream; these are not common uses case for Enum (usually you iterate over enum values, but rarely you need to transform, map and collect them).

If you need only to do an action over each elements perhaps you should expose only a forEach method

```
     public static void forEach(Consumer<Letter> action) {
            Arrays.stream(Letter.values()).forEach(action);
     }

     .... //example of usage
     Letter.forEach(e->System.out.println(e));
```

Comment: *"rarely you need to transform, map and collect them"* Well that depends on what you're doing with them. Nowadays `enum` is recommended as a replacement for e.g. bit flags and things like that. This is facilitated by [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html).

Comment: @Radiodef in fact it seems strange because usually you don't process the flags, you process the data that contains a flag (or flags) in it.

Comment: @Radiodef EnumSet is a Set which is a Collection and Collection has the stream() method so in java8 if you use EnumSet you already have the stream capabilites

Comment: @Giovanni That's true. I guess my own point validates your hypothesis in a way.

Comment: `System.out::println` is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 5):

I think the shortest code to get a `Stream` of enum constants is `Stream.of(Letter.values())`. It's not as nice as `Letter.values().stream()` but that's an issue with arrays, not specifically enums.

> Moreover, why don't enums have a `stream()` method?

You are right that the nicest possible call would be `Letter.stream()`. Unfortunately a class cannot have two methods with the same signature, so it would not be possible to implicitly add a static method `stream()` to every enum (in the same way that every enum has an implicitly added static method `values()`) as this would break every existing enum that already has a static or instance method without parameters called `stream()`.

> Is this approach OK?

I think so. The drawback is that `stream` is a static method, so there is no way to avoid code duplication; it would have to be added to every enum separately.